# how to add a scrollview into a tabbed page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, scrollview, tabbedpage

We are developing Xamarin.IOS shopping cart application in  c#  using visual studio 2017, We are using tabbed page, in that tabbed page we are  having more than four tab, we are getting an option “more” the content page, My query is how to add a scroll view into a tabbed page in order to avoid the more option, any help is appreciated

Comment: It is impossible unless you customize the tabbar.

Comment: Please let us know, how to customize the tabbar

Comment: Give me some sample code or link(Tabbed page with scroll)

Comment: There is no option in customize the tabbar, What can i do further